# Subclassing the creation of Buttons with their respective callback

Tags: python, discord.py

I am currently learning about discord.ui buttons and i want them to be subclassed since I find them to static otherwise.
I have come a long way of figuring it out but I can't quiet get the view to reset correctly (I have commented the code so you will see where the problem lies).

This is the code of the ButtonCreation subclass with Button from discord.ui import (this is the old code (I leave it as reference))

```
class ButtonCreation(Button):
    def __init__(self, label, style, emoji):
        super().__init__(label=label, style=style, emoji=emoji)

    async def callback(self, interaction):
        # define view again... this will make it empty. Some way to pass on the content of original view?
        # or maybe subclassing View instead of Button
        view = discord.ui.View()

        # checking if current pressed buttons style equals "success"/green
        if self.style == discord.ButtonStyle.success:

            # change the style to gray
            self.style = discord.ButtonStyle.gray
            view.add_item(self)

            # edit the original message with new view
            await interaction.response.edit_message(view=view)
        else:
            await interaction.response.send_message('This Button has the style: ' + str(self.style))
```

This is the command cog where the button gets created by passing the arguments.
(arguments were changed to how the new version needs them to be)

```
@client.command()
    async def myroles(self, ctx):

        # Buttons being created
        button1 = ButtonCreation(ctx=ctx, label='TSLinked', style=discord.ButtonStyle.green, custom_id="tslinked", emoji=None, row=0)
        button2 = ButtonCreation(ctx=ctx, label='TSLinked', style=discord.ButtonStyle.gray, custom_id="tsadmin", emoji=None, row=1)
        button3 = ButtonCreation(ctx=ctx, label='TSLinked', style=discord.ButtonStyle.danger, custom_id="tsserveradmin", emoji=None, row=2)

        # defining view plus adding buttons into view
        view = View()

        view.add_item(button1)
        view.add_item(button2)
        view.add_item(button3)

        # send view with text above
        await ctx.channel.send('Test!', view=view)
```

There is actually everything working except that I can't get the original view over to the callback to get all of the original buttons.
So the current flow is that all 3 buttons are shown with their according colour and when you press button1 (since green == "ButtonStyle.success") the button colour is changed to gray and gets put into the view which afterwards gets send to the channel.

What should happen: After the green button being pressed the buttons should stay the same except the green button which should switch to gray.
Thanks in advance to anyone willing to lend a hand.

**Solution**

```
# ButtonCreation subclass with Button from discord.ui import
class ButtonCreation(Button):
    # init needs ctx and at best custom_id or row to do all you need
    def __init__(self, ctx, label, style, emoji, custom_id, row):
        super().__init__(label=label, style=style, custom_id=custom_id, emoji=emoji, row=row)
        self.ctx = ctx

    async def callback(self, interaction):
        # checks if Button style is green
        if self.style == discord.ButtonStyle.green:
            
            # changes button to grey
            self.style = discord.ButtonStyle.grey
            
            # self.ctx can interact with channel and user just like ctx would in normal commands
            await self.ctx.channel.send('test')
            
            # remove your button (self) before adding it again since you can't "replace" it just like that
            self.view.remove_item(self)
            
            # add the Button (self) to the view by using self.view.add_item.
            self.view.add_item(self)

            # add the view to the edit or send_message method with self.view 
            await interaction.response.edit_message(view=self.view)
```

If you need a little clarification:
self is the Button thats how you call the arguments.
the Button also has "View" as object so you can actually get all the buttons that are saved in it.
so before adding the button to the view (self.view) you can change the values of the button and add them again.
Things like row are fixed for the single purpose of the buttons actually needing to stay in the same position, otherwise they would be added behind all others.

Really hope this helps others aswell.